# call the custom event after Rest/v1 API call for create new product magento 2

Tags: magento2, rest-api

**Currently**, we are using the nchannel to push and update the catalog product.
We need to disable the item when they push the new item. After inserting the Qty and other information we manually enable that product.

**can anyone let us know how can we get the Rest/v1 API log or event?**

Answer (score 0):

Check it in your php file:

```
$ch = curl_init('dev.magento2.com/rest/V1/products/xyz');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
'Content-Type: application/json'
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'PHPSESSID=' . $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);

$json = json_decode($result);
```

Comment: Not want to call the rest API. I need to write a log for the third party API call for my site.